# Nextjs: Avoid change css className after run

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

This is my code:

`<div className={styles.name}></div>`

After run the app, in inspect element my class changed to this:

`style_name__AYkko`

How can I stop it?

Comment: What do you expect `{styles.name}` to resolve to on render? This is part of CSS modules to scope CSS, add unique identifiers, to avoid clashing with other CSS the in the application. You could always just use `className="theClassYouWant"` instead of CSS modules.

Comment: If you stop it, it will no longer work.. So I wouldn't try to do that. It looks like you're using CSS modules. In order for them to work as intended, they need to have a unique name so they do not interfere with other modules.

Answer (score 2):

The only way you can do what you want to do is importing your stylesheet inside `_app.js` to have it globally scoped and avoid using `css-modules`. At this point you can use your classes inside regular `classNames` without getting the unique hash on inspected elements

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the class definition in a :global {} block

```
:global {
    .name {
        // css definitions
    }
}
```